# How to get $3D$ point coordinates of $2D$ point on a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, plane-geometry

Given a normal vector of a $3D$ plane and a $x$-$y$ coordinates of a point *on the plane* with origin of the plane $(0, 0)$ being at $(0, 0, 0)$, how can I get $3D$ coordinates of the point?

Basically, I need to rotate a point on a plane with normal vector $(1, 0, 0)$ with respect to an arbitrary normal vector.

I really don't know even where to start. What should be the resulting algorithm. Should it be some sort of transformation matrix?

Comment: It will indeed be a linear transformation. Find the images of $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$; this will be enough to determine the images of an arbitrary point.

Comment: I don't know what are the images.

Comment: Then you are out of luck. Without knowing how the coordinate system on the plane aligns with 3D coordinates, the best you can tell about the location of the point in space from its 2D coordinates is that is lies on a certain circle. Come back when you are willing to provide enough information to actually solve the problem.